# How to test a function with a module whose constant cannot be changed

Tags: ruby, rspec

How can I write a test to test function `hey` defined as below? Module `CONSTANT` is loaded into `spec_helper`, and its variables are frozen and cannot be changed.

```
module CONSTANT
  X=1
  Y=2
  self.freeze
end

def hey
  if CONSTANT::X == 1
    puts "OKOK"
  else
    puts "NOT OK"
  end
end
```

How can I write a test to test the else clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `const_set` class method.

EDIT: I just noticed the `freeze` command.  I have updated my example.

Example:

```
CONSTANT = CONSTANT.dup
CONSTANT.const_set("X",0) # this will create a warning message when it sets the value
puts CONSTANT::X # returns 0
```